# Object creation inside or outside loop

Tags: python, loops, object, python-3.x

What's the most efficient (in term of memory management and/or speed), and why :

```
for r in rows:
    o = Obj(r.name, r.value)
```

or

```
o = Obj()
for r in rows:
   o.name = r.name
   o.value = r.value
```

my guts feeling is it's equal: each time you create an object and overwrite the preceeding, or you do it at attribute level. But i'm not sure i'm correct.

Comment: What does `timeit` tell you?

Comment: those two pieces of code do two different things - the first creates an object inside of a loop, but once the loop goes to the next value of `r`, the object will be destroyed. The second piece of code creates one object, and each iteration of the loop overwrites the previous one. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @MattDMo, yes i know, but in term of memory management, i just to have confirmation that it's equal regarding how python3 manages memory. Final it's pumping data from DB into object.